# Android Paint stroke width positioning

Tags: android, drawing, paint, stroke

Given this code to draw a line:

```
Paint p;

p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
p.setColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
p.setStrokeWidth(21);

canvas.drawLine(0,50,100,50,p);
```

there are 3 possible stroke-drawing strategies:

- Inside: The line is painted in the rectangle (0,50,100,70)
- Center: The line is painted in the rectangle (0,40,100,60)
- Outside: The line is painted in the rectangle (0,30,100,50)

In practice it appears that default behavior follows the Center strategy. Is it possible to modify a paint to produce results corresponding to one of the other strategies?

Comment: what is your actual requirement? what you exact need?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer, Well, I adapted my code to reality. But if you are curious, I was drawing the court of a game I was designing, and I needed pixel accuracy control to draw lines.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No you can't; the stroke is always centered. The only things you can control are:

- [stroke miter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getStrokeMiter())
- [stroke cap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getStrokeCap())
- [stroke join](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getStrokeJoin())
- [stroke width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getStrokeWidth())

You must manually account for the stroke width when defining your drawing paths.